# 1 dimensional irreducible representation of $D_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to determine all 1 dimensional representation of dihedral group $D_n$ for all n?
Since a 1 dimensional representation character $\chi $ is a homomorphism from the group to $GL_1$, therefore its kernel is a normal subgroup. I think it is possible to think about this question from normal subgroup of $D_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group $D_n$ is generated by two elements $r$ and $s$ such that $r^n=1$, $s^2=1$ and $srs=r^{-1}$.

Suppose that $\chi:D\to\mathbb C^\times$ is a group homomorphism and let $a=\chi(r)$ and $b=\chi(s)$: these two numbers completely determine $\chi$. We have $a^n=1$, $b^2=1$ and $bab=a^{-1}$, because of the relations that $r$ and $s$ satisfy. Conversely, since the relations above constitute a presentation of $D$, every choice of $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb C^\times$ satisfying these three equations determines a homomorphism $\chi$.

The last two equations imply that $a$ and $b$ are in $\{\pm1\}$. There are two cases:

- if $n$ is even, the equation $a^n=1$ is satisfied automatically, and we have four different ways of choosing $a$ and $b$,
- if instead $n$ is odd, then that equation implies that $a=1$, so the only liberty we have is in choosing $b$ in $\{\pm1\}$.

It follows that there are either four or two $1$-dimensional representations, depending on the parity of $n$, and this description in fact determines them.